# @FieldMatch cannot be resolved to a type (Spring Framework)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I was trying to use the annotation `@FieldMatch` in a web application with Spring Framework.

These are the jars i added

[image]

but Eclipse tells me "FieldMatch cannot be resolved to a type"; I thought I needed Hibernate jars but I was wrong. What jar i need?

Answer (score 0):

It's in hibernate validator, if you're using maven, add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I edited my post adding the jar i already added to my Java Build Path in Eclipse.

Comment: I also added hibernate-validator-5.1.2.Final but i still get the same problem.